# Can I get any info about a failed CanvasAuthorizer.Authorize()

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I am getting several failed calls in my error log, and these may be fine (new user registering, etc). However, is it possible to get any info about these failed hits. At this stage, there's no FB User Id, etc. (they've not authorised yet), but is there any way to get a 'fail reason', just so I have some info about these errors? I suspect not, but I thought I'd ask! :)

Comment: This seems to fail intermittently, even for users who have previously approved the app. I suspect this is due to fb being 'busy'. Is there a way to make this call asynch? I would loop round until it succeeds, but there's no way of knowing if the fail is due to 'busy', or because they actually do need to authorise the app! Hey-ho